# Как передать контекст вызова в функцию прототипа?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не понимаю как передать this в новый объект. Если это делать из конструктора то все отлично работает а если делать через прототип то нет.

```
const ACCOUNT = require('./account');

function Model(dataBase, session){
    this.db = dataBase;
    this.session = session;
}

Model.prototype.account = new ACCOUNT(this);
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
const ACCOUNT = require('./account');

function Model(dataBase, session){
    this.db = dataBase;
    this.session = session;
}

Model.prototype.account = function() {
    return new ACCOUNT(this);
}
```

Но не работает, не могу получить доступ к методам ACCOUNT.

**UPDATE:**
Объект Account

```
function Account(global){
  this.global = global;
}

Account.prototype.test = function(){
  return this.global.session;
}

module.exports = Account;
```

В дальнейшем не могу получить метод *test* объекта **Model** пишет что это не функция.

```
let model = new ModelObj(core.db, request.session);
console.log(await model.account.test());
```

Comment: _не могу получить доступ к методам ACCOUNT._ - в каком месте? Приведенный блоки кода отличаются значением `this`, которые в них используются. Кроме того, в первом случае объект ACCOUNT создается один раз, а во втором, каждый раз при вызове метода `.account`

Comment: При использовании второго вариант описания Model не могу вызвать метод test. В идеале конечно хотелось бы как то передать в функцию прототипа - this но как понял в первом варианте this имеет совершенно другое значение.

Comment: И еще немного офтопа, у какого из трех вариантов (1. инициализации account в конструкторе,  2. как прототип, 3. через обертку в другую функцию) будет выше быстродействие и более экономично по памяти с учетом того что сам объект Model будет большим?

Comment: Это тебе только профилировщики скажут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором случае нельзя обратиться к метода `Account`, просто потому, что метод

```
Model.prototype.account
```

это **функция**, которая возвращает новый объект Account.

А у функции нет метода `test`.

То есть вызов должен быть заменен на

```
await model.account().test()
```

Либо должен заполняться внутри конструктора, если нужен доступ к конкретному объекту Model:

```
const ACCOUNT = require('./account');

function Model(dataBase, session){
    this.db = dataBase;
    this.session = session;
    this.account = new ACCOUNT(this);
}
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что в первом случае, в качестве `this` будет передан объект модуля, а не объект класса `Model`.